# Cookie notification script

Tags: javascript, cookies, notifications, footer, message

I am using Wordpress and would like to use a light weight cookie notification script rather plugin for WP.

I found this useful script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="cookieinfo"
    src="//cookieinfoscript.com/js/cookieinfo.min.js">
</script>
```

from https://cookieinfoscript.com/

My question is, is this script safe? They included a link to their website in the code and also there is some kind or tracker in the script. What's that?

Would like to hear your opinion.

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
! function(e) {
"use strict";
var t = e,
    i = t.document,
    o = "cbinstance";
var n = {
        get: function(e) {
            return decodeURIComponent(i.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:(?:^|.*;)\\s*" + encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$"), "$1")) || null
        },
        set: function(e, t, o, n, s, r) {
            if (!e || /^(?:expires|max\-age|path|domain|secure)$/i.test(e)) return !1;
            var a = "";
            if (o) switch (o.constructor) {
                case Number:
                    a = o === 1 / 0 ? "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT" : "; max-age=" + o;
                    break;
                case String:
                    a = "; expires=" + o;
                    break;
                case Date:
                    a = "; expires=" + o.toUTCString()
            }
            return i.cookie = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(t) + a + (s ? "; domain=" + s : "") + (n ? "; path=" + n : "") + (r ? "; secure" : ""), !0
        },
        has: function(e) {
            return new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + encodeURIComponent(e).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=").test(i.cookie)
        },
        remove: function(e, t, o) {
            return !(!e || !this.has(e)) && (i.cookie = encodeURIComponent(e) + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" + (o ? "; domain=" + o : "") + (t ? "; path=" + t : ""), !0)
        }
    },
    s = {
        merge: function() {
            var e, t = {},
                i = 0,
                o = arguments.length;
            if (0 === o) return t;
            for (; i < o; i++)
                for (e in arguments[i]) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(arguments[i], e) && (t[e] = arguments[i][e]);
            return t
        },
        str2bool: function(e) {
            switch ((e = "" + e).toLowerCase()) {
                case "false":
                case "no":
                case "0":
                case "":
                    return !1;
                default:
                    return !0
            }
        },
        fade_in: function(e) {
            e.style.opacity < 1 && (e.style.opacity = (parseFloat(e.style.opacity) + .05).toFixed(2), t.setTimeout(function() {
                s.fade_in(e)
            }, 50))
        },
        get_data_attribs: function(e) {
            var t = {};
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, "dataset")) t = e.dataset;
            else {
                var i, o = e.attributes;
                for (i in o)
                    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, i)) {
                        var n = o[i];
                        if (/^data-/.test(n.name)) t[s.camelize(n.name.substr(5))] = n.value
                    }
            }
            return t
        },
        normalize_keys: function(e) {
            var t = {};
            for (var i in e)
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, i)) {
                    var o = s.camelize(i);
                    t[o] = e[o] ? e[o] : e[i]
                }
            return t
        },
        camelize: function(e) {
            for (var t = "-", i = e.indexOf(t); - 1 != i;) {
                var o = i === e.length - 1,
                    n = o ? "" : e[i + 1],
                    s = n.toUpperCase(),
                    r = o ? t : t + n;
                i = (e = e.replace(r, s)).indexOf(t)
            }
            return e
        },
        find_script_by_id: function(e) {
            for (var t = i.getElementsByTagName("script"), o = 0, n = t.length; o < n; o++)
                if (e === t[o].id) return t[o];
            return null
        }
    },
    r = s.find_script_by_id("cookieinfo"),
    a = e.cookieinfo = function(e) {
        this.init(e)
    };
a.prototype = {
    cookiejar: n,
    init: function(t) {
        this.inserted = !1, this.closed = !1, this.test_mode = !1;
        if (this.default_options = {
                cookie: "we-love-cookies",
                closeText: "&#10006;",
                cookiePath: "/",
                debug: !1,
                expires: 1 / 0,
                zindex: 1e20,
                mask: !1,
                maskOpacity: .5,
                maskBackground: "#999",
                height: "auto",
                minHeight: "21px",
                bg: "#eee",
                fg: "#333",
                link: "#31A8F0",
                divlink: "#000",
                divlinkbg: "#F1D600",
                position: "bottom",
                message: "We use cookies to enhance your experience. By continuing to visit this site you agree to our use of cookies.",
                linkmsg: "More info",
                scriptmsg: "Cookie Info Script",
                moreinfo: "http://wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie",
                scriptinfo: "https://cookieinfoscript.com",
                tracking: "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==",
                effect: null,
                fontSize: "14px",
                fontFamily: "verdana, arial, sans-serif",
                instance: o,
                textAlign: "center",
                acceptOnScroll: !1
            }, this.options = this.default_options, this.script_el = r, this.script_el) {
            var i = s.get_data_attribs(this.script_el);
            this.options = s.merge(this.options, i)
        }
        t && (t = s.normalize_keys(t), this.options = s.merge(this.options, t)), o = this.options.instance, this.options.zindex = parseInt(this.options.zindex, 10), this.options.mask = s.str2bool(this.options.mask), "string" == typeof this.options.expires && "function" == typeof e[this.options.expires] && (this.options.expires = e[this.options.expires]), "function" == typeof this.options.expires && (this.options.expires = this.options.expires()), this.script_el && this.run()
    },
    log: function() {
        "undefined" != typeof console && console.log.apply(console, arguments)
    },
    run: function() {
        if (!this.agreed()) {
            var e = this;
            ! function(e, t) {
                var i = !1,
                    o = !0,
                    n = e.document,
                    s = n.documentElement,
                    r = n.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                    a = n.addEventListener ? "removeEventListener" : "detachEvent",
                    c = n.addEventListener ? "" : "on",
                    l = function(o) {
                        "readystatechange" == o.type && "complete" != n.readyState || (("load" == o.type ? e : n)[a](c + o.type, l, !1), !i && (i = !0) && t.call(e, o.type || o))
                    },
                    p = function() {
                        try {
                            s.doScroll("left")
                        } catch (e) {
                            return void setTimeout(p, 50)
                        }
                        l("poll")
                    };
                if ("complete" == n.readyState) t.call(e, "lazy");
                else {
                    if (n.createEventObject && s.doScroll) {
                        try {
                            o = !e.frameElement
                        } catch (e) {}
                        o && p()
                    }
                    n[r](c + "DOMContentLoaded", l, !1), n[r](c + "readystatechange", l, !1), e[r](c + "load", l, !1)
                }
            }(t, function() {
                e.insert()
            })
        }
    },
    build_viewport_mask: function() {
        var e = null;
        if (!0 === this.options.mask) {
            var t = this.options.maskOpacity,
                o = '<div id="cookieinfo-mask" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background:' + this.options.maskBackground + ";zoom:1;filter:alpha(opacity=" + 100 * t + ");opacity:" + t + ";z-index:" + this.options.zindex + ';"></div>',
                n = i.createElement("div");
            n.innerHTML = o, e = n.firstChild
        }
        return e
    },
    agree: function() {
        return this.cookiejar.set(this.options.cookie, 1, this.options.expires, this.options.cookiePath), !0
    },
    agreed: function() {
        return this.cookiejar.has(this.options.cookie)
    },
    close: function() {
        return this.inserted && (this.closed || (this.element && this.element.parentNode.removeChild(this.element), this.element_mask && this.element_mask.parentNode.removeChild(this.element_mask), this.closed = !0)), this.closed
    },
    agree_and_close: function() {
        return this.agree(), this.close()
    },
    cleanup: function() {
        return this.close(), this.unload()
    },
    unload: function() {
        return this.script_el && this.script_el.parentNode.removeChild(this.script_el), e[o] = void 0, !0
    },
    insert: function() {
        this.element_mask = this.build_viewport_mask();
        var e = this.options.zindex;
        this.element_mask && (e += 1);
        var t = i.createElement("div");
        t.className = "cookieinfo", t.style.position = "fixed", t.style.left = 0, t.style.right = 0, t.style.height = this.options.height, t.style.minHeight = this.options.minHeight, t.style.zIndex = e, t.style.background = this.options.bg, t.style.color = this.options.fg, t.style.lineHeight = t.style.minHeight, t.style.padding = "8px 18px", t.style.fontFamily = this.options.fontFamily, t.style.fontSize = this.options.fontSize, t.style.textAlign = this.options.textAlign, "top" === this.options.position ? t.style.top = 0 : t.style.bottom = 0, t.innerHTML = '<div class="cookieinfo-close" style="float:right;display:block;padding:5px 8px 5px 8px;min-width:100px;margin-left:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;border-top-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-right-radius:5px;border-bottom-left-radius:5px;">' + this.options.closeText + '</div><span style="display:block;padding:5px 0 5px 0;">' + this.options.message + " <a>" + this.options.linkmsg + "</a><img> <a>" + this.options.scriptmsg + "</a></span>", this.element = t;
        var o = t.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        o.href = this.options.moreinfo, o.style.textDecoration = "none", o.style.color = this.options.link;
        var n = t.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];
        n.href = this.options.scriptinfo, n.style.textDecoration = "none", n.style.display = "none", n.style.color = this.options.link;
        var r = t.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        r.style.cursor = "pointer", r.style.color = this.options.divlink, r.style.background = this.options.divlinkbg, r.style.textAlign = "center";
        var a = t.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

        function c(e, t, i) {
            var o = e.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent",
                n = e.addEventListener ? "" : "on";
            e[o](n + t, i, !1)
        }
        a.src = this.options.tracking, a.style.display = "none";
        var l = this;
        c(r, "click", function() {
            l.agree_and_close()
        }), this.element_mask && (c(this.element_mask, "click", function() {
            l.agree_and_close()
        }), i.body.appendChild(this.element_mask)), this.options.acceptOnScroll && c(window, "scroll", function() {
            l.agree_and_close()
        }), i.body.appendChild(this.element), this.inserted = !0, "fade" === this.options.effect ? (this.element.style.opacity = 0, s.fade_in(this.element)) : this.element.style.opacity = 1
    }
}, r && (e[o] || (e[o] = new a)) }(window);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. On this forum it is expected that you do as much investigation as you can, and ask for help when you get stuck. You can read more at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case it would be better if you have downloaded the code to have a look at it, and need help in understanding what it is doing.

Comment: Mikkel, thanks for your replay. I have downloaded the code of course, also I looked at it too, for a long time actually. My html and css knowledge is high and I can do that part of the job but my javascript knowledge is poor, I was able to identify some kind of tracker in the code and their link which is generated and included at the front end page and hidden with css.